# Redirecting a successful ajax call with React-Router

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm getting *Cannot read property 'router' of undefined* with the code below.

*this.transitionTo('home')* is bugging, and I'm guessing it's because of the context of this. I tried binding the ajax call to this, and it didn't help either.

Any thoughts on how to simply redirect to either 'home' or '/' after this successful ajax call?

I've tried both the Navigation (transitionTo) and the History (this.pushState) mixins.

Edit: In the meantime I found a hacky working solution that uses a page refresh. Within the ajax .done section:

```
history.pushState({},'','/')
window.location.reload()
```

Code:

```
var Router = ReactRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Routes = ReactRouter.Routes;
var Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;
var History = ReactRouter.History;

var Login = React.createClass({

mixins: [ History ],
mixins: [ Navigation ],

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }
},

submit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    var data = {
       email: this.state.email,
       password: this.state.password,
    }

     // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/sessions',
        data: data
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            App.logIn(data.email)
            alert('login successful!')
            this.transitionTo('home')
            // this.history.pushState(null, '/home')
            // this.pushState(null, '/home')
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            alert('No Such Email or Incorrect Password')
        });
},

handleEmailChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
},

handlePasswordChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
},    

render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
            Login To Your Account
            <br/>
            <form onSubmit={this.submit} >
                Email: <input label="Email:" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                <br/>
                Password: <input label="Password:" type="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context is changing in the inner function. The easiest way (in my opinion) to fix this is to place `var _this = this` in your outer function,  then use `_this.transitionTo` in your callback.